# Revoke Access to the app Gmail API

Tags: node.js, gmail-api

How could I revoke access to the app from backend Node.js
As we have the option to generate access_token using the method refreshaccesstoken(). So is there any similar method that 
I could use to revoke access for the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [revoke a token programmatically](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke) by sending a request with either the `access_token` or the `refresh_token`.

```
POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke?token={token} HTTP/1.1
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Comment: Hi. How do I access to token in the FileDataStore? Should I store it as a member variable of my utility and then can use it to revoke? Or can we read the FileDataStore object that is in their folder and use that?